# Strange resource dictionary warnings appear in output window even when the WPF trace settings are turned off

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, warnings, trace

I am using Visual studio 2011 beta with the april 2012 update installed .I have my Debugging options -> Output window > WPF trace settings all the values including Resource Dictionaries turned off.But I still continue to see warning messages like

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; 
     ResourceKey='CheckBoxCooperStyle1'
```

How to debug this type of warnings provided they are not false positives ?

Comment: Do you have a checkox and what are its current style settings?

Comment: @OmegaMan There are some check boxes which use the style CheckBoxCooperStyle1 and i am very sure that the style is present in the XAML as the resource and i can see at run time that styles are getting applied correctly and this is just one of the warnings

Comment: Reply from Microsoft support team  
"Thanks for the update. I was afraid of that, since my testing found similar results. 
It seems there is some internal WPF tracing code which does not adhere to the specified settings. 
I've reached out to a broader group of WPF experts to see if anyone has further ideas on if there is a way to fully disable the WPF trace settings. 
In the meantime, I don’t have any suggestions other than finding the ResourceDictionary (or the relevant type) and correcting the issues that the trace output is warning about."

Comment: Nice....I wondered about that. Is this a connect issue where they responded?

Comment: @OmegaMan We have premium support for our organization ,so I contacted them directly .The support person told he will add it to their internal feature request queue and asked me to also log the defect in the connect site to track externally ,which I am yet to do

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reply from Microsoft support team "Thanks for the update. I was afraid of that, since my testing found similar results. It seems there is some internal WPF tracing code which does not adhere to the specified settings.  In the meantime, We don’t have any suggestions other than finding the Resource Dictionary (or the relevant type) and correcting the issues that the trace output is warning about.

if a debugger was attached, there will always be some WPF tracing emitted regardless of the settings specified in the IDE (or in the app.config). Unfortunately, the output you are receiving appears to fall into this category. Regrettably, there is no way to turn off all the WPF trace output from being emitted

We could certainly file a feature request for the product for this to be considered in a future release, but otherwise I don’t see a way for you to avoid the issue in the current release.

Comment: 2 years later. I still found this issue... Can I just ignore this then, however annoying it may be?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus try to take a close look at what it is complaining about and if you are sure everything looks all right then you can ignore the warnings.Yes I agree it is definitely annoying sometimes as you have put extra effort to differentiate between the true problems and false positives

Comment: I had a bunch of warnings that said they couldn't find the resources(it could). I moved all m resources usings to a central Theme file and they went away...

Answer (score 14):

I got these Messages when mixing static resources and dynamic resources.
Setting all the Problematic Resource settings to StaticResource solved the problem.
Instead of:

```
Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxCooperStyle1}"
```

Use:

```
Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxCooperStyle1}"
```

Comment: This can solve the problem in some cases ,but in my case there are number of unnecessary warnings regardless of whether you use a StaticResource or a DynamicResource