# Warning about non-existing existing resource, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamicresource

I'm dynamically loading a `ResourceDictionary` and adding it to `MergedDictionaries` like the following:

```
var mergedDictionaries = Resources.MergedDictionaries;
mergedDictionaries.Clear();

// Generic styles            
ResourceDictionary vsStyles = new ResourceDictionary();
vsStyles.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/VSTheme/VSStyles.xaml");
mergedDictionaries.Add(vsStyles);

// Theme-dependent styles
ResourceDictionary bright = new ResourceDictionary();
bright.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Images/Bright.xaml");
mergedDictionaries.Add(bright);
```

The Bright.xaml looks like the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <BitmapImage UriSource="..\Images\Bright\folder-bright.png" x:Key="FolderItemImage" />
    <BitmapImage UriSource="..\Images\Bright\class-bright.png" x:Key="ClassItemImage" />
(...)
</ResourceDictionary>
```

These images are being used in treeviewitems displayed in the UI:

```
<Image x:Name="iIcon" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0, 1, 3, 1" Source="{DynamicResource FolderItemImage}"/>
```

Generally, they display without problems, but when I run the program (despite images being displayed correctly), I receive a lot of warnings:

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='NativeImage'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClassItemImage'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='NativeImage'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClassItemImage'
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Those errors could just be happening *before* the `ResourceDictionary` is loaded... do they stop once it has been loaded? If that is the case, then you can just ignore them... after all, they are just warnings.

I had a similar situation with `Binding`s, but there is a `Binding.IsAsync` property that I could set that tells the `Binding` that values will not come immediately. This made the warnings disappear. Unfortunately, I don't think that there is a similar property for `Resources`, so you may just have to live with it, or try to load your `ResourceDictionary` earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question got "answered" years ago in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822003/strange-resource-dictionary-warnings-appear-in-output-window-even-when-the-wpf-t).

Unfortunately "answered" means that it's a problem with WPF that Microsoft hasn't fixed yet.