# Strange warning in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom usercontrol let's call it `MyUserControl`. I can't paste it because it contains 1 tabcontrol + 2 datagrids.
My UC loads a resourceDictionnary which contains all my styles.

I have a grid in my window called `grid_1`.

When I click on a button I just do this :

```
grid1.Children.Clear();
grid1.Children.Add(new MyUserControl());
```

And it works fine, I don't have any error or warning. But when I click again on my button I have 10 time this warning in the output :

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression'; ResourceKey.HashCode='43311876'; ResourceKey.Type='System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression'
```

Is there a way to find a trace more detailed to find where the issue comes from ?
How is it possible that I only have errors on the second time my control is loaded ?

As you can imagine there is no reference to `System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression` in all my code.

Have you any idea to resolve this issue or at least help me finding the source ?

Thank you!

Comment: It's difficult to tell without your XAML but assuming you're using 
{StaticResource resourceName}, {DynamicResource resourceName} or {x:Static resourceName}. You cannot trace something like that. There's some faulty XAML you have to fix.

Comment: That is the WPF debugger.

Here is a question about the same issue from several years ago.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822003/strange-resource-dictionary-warnings-appear-in-output-window-even-when-the-wpf-t

Comment: FWIW, there were dozens of these warnings emitted from an app that I maintained once. I never figured out what they meant and the app was working fine.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers ! That's complicated to paste all the control + all the styles related that's why I was asking for advice.
My app is working fine but if there is something wrong with my styles I'd rather fix it !
I've found the link you pasted but it doesn't really give me answers on this one. 
Is this ok to add the control in my grid like I did ? (because it displays the errors only on the second loading)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old but I could only find vague answers indicating that a mix of "StaticResource" and "DynamicResource" can cause these warnings.

In my case the warnings appeared when I deleted entries from a DataGrid. The entries were bound to an ObservableCollection.

The problem was caused by a ResourceDictionary (XAML) that contained Colors and Brushes. The Brushes used the Colors as DynamicResource, e.g.

**SolidColorBrush x:Key="TableBorderBrush" Color="{*DynamicResource* TableBorderColor}"**

In the XAML file that contained the DataGrid one of those brushes was used for an element as StaticResource. So a StaticResource was used which used a DynamicResource. The warnings disappeared after using a *StaticResource* for the Brush.