# How do I track down a WPF "ResourceDictionary Warning 9 Resource not found" when it doesn't tell me the resource key?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

When running my WPF app I am seeing many warning messages in the output window:

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found
```

However, unlike all of the related questions I have seen posted on Stack Overflow (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10822003/4265041)), none of these warnings tell me which resource key (or keys) is/are causing the problem.

**Is there any way to get Visual Studio to tell me this information?** I have tried changing the WPF Trace Settings in Debug Options, but these have had no effect. Oddly, I still get the resource dictionary warnings even when the related trace setting is set to "Off".

---

**Background information**

I am making use of an MVVM library called [Stylet](https://github.com/canton7/Stylet/wiki) and these warnings seem to appear when one view is switched out for another. Other than a slight (but noticeable) delay, the warnings don't seem to affect the operation of the app.

That said, I suspect that the warnings are more likely due to another library, [Material Design](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit), as I added that later in development and don't recall seeing the warnings until after that point.

My code is split across two different C# projects: one for the UI stuff (controls, styles, converters, brushes, etc) and the other for the main app. The Stylet and Material Design NuGet packages are referenced by the UI project; the UI project is then referenced by the main app project. Both projects are .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: I wouldn't ignore warnings. Even a little exception means noticable delay, means poor user experience. But wpf is hard to debug, usually you should have 0 warnings and when you see 1 appear - then you know it has something to do with latest change you did. If you already let many accumulate, you can start pin-pointing them by commenting/uncommenting.

Comment: @Sinatr Yeah, I really would like to track these down, even if it turns out they're spurious.  I've also tried turning off (ie. commenting out) bits of the UI, and switching back to WPF's default control styles, but to no avail. It's still not obvious where the problem lies.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the Material Design library. The warnings seem to get written when controls are unloaded. [Related GitHub issue here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/1867) for anyone interested.